# Line number in editors

Tags: feature-request, editor

Since the post/question editor automatically wraps long lines, it is helpful to have line numbers to see whether it's a newline or just a space, since Markdown is sensitive to whitespaces. Line numbers in post/question revision history would also be helpful (currently I can only identify lines with "inspect element").

This is not asking for line number *in code listing* in the *rendered HTML*, but instead in **editor**:

> [image]

It should have been explained in description of [editor](/questions/tagged/editor).

Comment: Added a screenshot, if that's not what you meant feel free to rollback, but explain what you do have in mind please.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Exactly what I want. I would prefer the same font size as texts though.

Comment: True, I was afraid that using it in the mockup would cause people not to notice it, that's why I used bigger font.

Comment: @shadow aren't there 2 newlines in that text? According to the fence post problem it should display 1 at the first block, 2 at the empty line, then 3 at the second block

Comment: @Ferrybig dunno, not really familiar with numbering that much - you might be correct, if and when SE will do it I'm sure they'll do the correct thing, I just gave rough sketch, more for people like me who weren't sure what OP meant.